# Smallest change to a set of vectors that makes them orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have a few vectors that are almost orthogonal (they are not all unit length). Measured in terms of their mean squared displacement, how can I find the smallest change that makes them exactly orthogonal?

I can arrive at *an* answer with Gram–Schmidt, but I'm not sure if it will be optimal.

Comment: You should be able to read the answer out of a SVD decomposition.

Comment: How do I know that what comes out of the SVD decomposition is as close to my original vectors as possible?

Comment: Good question.  You should be able to figure out a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint sequence:  Consider the problem of finding the orthogonal matrix $U$ that maximizes $\text{tr} (DU)$, for  given diagonal matrix $D$ with non-negative  entries.  And then consider the problem of maximizing $\text{tr}( AU)$ when $A$ is  arbitrary.  Finally, consider the problem of *minimizing* the trace of $(B-U)'(B-U)$ with respect to orthogonal $U$, for given matrix $B$.

Comment: So, I appreciate the value in figuring things out for yourself, but I have to admit  I am curious: have I accidentally stumbled upon a question that is commonly asked as a homework assignment?

Comment: I tdon't know it its a standard homework question.  It seems a wee bit too complicated for that.  Maybe an extra credit problem?  Class project exercise?  Do you need help with my hint sequence?

Comment: This problem arose in an applied geographical scenario. Thanks for the hints, I was able to deduce the answer from them. If you don't mind I will post an answer to this question that spells out the steps; let me know if they are wrong. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of kimchi lover, we may proceed by noting that the trace is they key to a useful matrix dot product,
$$
 \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} b_{ij} = \mathrm{Tr}\, A'B
$$
Where $A'$ is the transpose of A. This operation has a nice geometrical interpretation: it is the sum of the dot products of each column in $A$ with each column in $B$.

If we would like to modify a matrix in a way that changes it as little as possible, we should minimize the magnitude of the difference between the old and new matrices. Using the above trace as the magnitude, we may write the expression that should be minimized:
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\,(A-O)'(A-O)
$$
Where $O$ is an orthogonal matrix and $A$ is the input matrix. We may simplify the trace to,
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\,A'A + \mathrm{Tr}\,O'O -2\mathrm{Tr}\,AO'
$$
Because $A$ is given and $O'O=I$, this minimization is equivalent to maximizing,
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\, AO'
$$
With the singular value decomposition $A=SDV'$, this leads to,
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\,DV'O'S
$$
From the matrix dot product identity above, it is clear that this is maximized when $V'O'S = I$, which implies that
$$
O'=VS' \therefore O= SV'
$$

Comment: Looks good to me.  I might add, that if your original  vectors span a subspace $A$ of less than full dimension, you can adjoin to them any orthonormal basis of the orthogonal complement of $A$, viz. $A^\perp$.  This makes all the matrices in sight in the above answer square.